# Override the postDate for entries so their URL works on the frontend?

Tags: frontend, postdate

Is it possible to override/disregard the postDate for all entries in a section so that they are visible on the frontend even if this date is in the future?

I realise I could add a dedicated date field — but keen to avoid this if possible as the fields for this entry are already quite complicated!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `status(null)` in your ElementQuery in order to fetch all items or you add `status(['pending', 'enabled'])` to pull all entries, that are not disabled and not expired

Comment: That works but when you click to view the actual entry you get a 404 error?

Comment: You have to either create a custom route or set their postDate to a valid value - because that's the indented way how the postDate works. Do you want to set the postDate for all entries in a section to now?